# Which environment variables are needed for kpsewhich to discover *.ini files?

Tags: texlive, installing, kpathsea, kpsewhich

I'm trying to use `--custom-bin` switch of `install-tl`. I've moved the TexLive's `kpsewhich` to my `custom_bin` directory. But `kpsewhich` fails to discover `*.ini` files and `*.cnf` files (`kpsewhich -progname=pdftex -format=tex pdfetex.ini`

Which environment variables I need to set to point `kpsewhich` to the currently-being-installed TexLive distribution? I've tried setting `TEXMFDIST` but it doesn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: TEXMFCNF for texmf.cnf,   .ini files are just tex source so TEXINPUTS for them but normally you put the master texmf.cnf at the right place relative to the location of the binary and then everything follows from there without setting any environment other than PATH

Comment: In theory, do I need to set just TEXINPUTS? Or should I also set TEXFMDIST etc?

Answer (score 1):

ini files are simply TeX souce so they are searched along TEXINPUTS although that isn't usually set in the environment but in a `texmf.cnf`  file.

`texmf.cnf` are searched along the paths set in the TEXMFCNF environment variable the default for which is set at compile time (as naturally you can't set it in a texmf.cnf file) the defaults (in `paths.h` in the texlive source) are as below (linebreaks added for readability)

```
#define DEFAULT_TEXMFCNF "{
$SELFAUTOLOC,
$SELFAUTOLOC/share/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTOLOC/share/texmf-dist/web2c,
$SELFAUTOLOC/share/texmf/web2c,
$SELFAUTOLOC/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTOLOC/texmf-dist/web2c,
$SELFAUTOLOC/texmf/web2c,
$SELFAUTODIR,
$SELFAUTODIR/share/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTODIR/share/texmf-dist/web2c,
$SELFAUTODIR/share/texmf/web2c,
$SELFAUTODIR/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTODIR/texmf-dist/web2c,
$SELFAUTODIR/texmf/web2c,
$SELFAUTOGRANDPARENT/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTOPARENT,
$SELFAUTOPARENT/share/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTOPARENT/share/texmf-dist/web2c,
$SELFAUTOPARENT/share/texmf/web2c,
$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-local/web2c,
$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-dist/web2c,
$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf/web2c}"
```

where SELFAUTOLOC is the location of the binary

Comment: Is there a way to override SELFAUTOLOC / SELFAUTOPARENT in env vars? My actual custom `pdftex` binaries are symlinked in custom bin location. It seems that SELFAUTOLOC are being determined relative to physical binary location and hence the `*.ini` and `*.cnf` files cannot be found.

Comment: well you can set TEXMFCNF in the environment then that isn't used at all, or since SELFAUTOLOC is the first path you can put teh texmf.cnf in the same directory as the binary or ...